# Cordova + Crosswalk

Tags: android-studio, apache-cordova, crosswalk

criei um projeto cordova normalmente:

```
cordova create myApp com.myapp myApp
```

depois entrei na pasta do projeto

```
cd myApp
```

adicionei a plataforma:

```
cordova platform add android
```

e adicionei o plugin do crosswalk

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Se eu importar o projeto no Android Studio ele me da um erro de pacote. Pesquisei e esse erro é porque precisa compilar o projeto para o plugin do crosswalk baixar algumas classes etc... Tentei compilar e:

```
cordova build android --release
```

Os erros sumiram, mas ele não compila e da vários erros de classes duplicadas...

```
C:\Users\GuilhermeAw\Desktop\teste\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\x86\release\org\xwalk\core\R.java
Error:(9, 14) java: duplicate class: org.xwalk.core.R
C:\Users\GuilhermeAw\Desktop\teste\platforms\android\build\generated\source\r\x86\release\com\teste\R.java
Error:(10, 14) java: duplicate class: com.teste.R
```

Se eu apago as classes aparece mais erros:

```
Error:Android Dex: [android] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [android] com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/cordova/AuthenticationToken;
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:591)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:546)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:528)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:188)
Error:Android Dex: [android] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:336)
```

Eu acredito que esteja faltando alguma coisa, mas como é a primeira vez que trabalho com o crosswalk não sei lidar com esses erros, alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Efetuei os passos que você descreveu porém antes de adicionar a lib do crosswalk eu criei dentro da pasta **platforms/android** o arquivo **gradle.properties**, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
cdvMinSdkVersion=20
```

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/).

Resumindo segui os seguintes passos:

```
npm install -g cordova

cordova create myApp com.myapp myApp

cd myApp

cordova platform add android
```

Criei dentro da pasta **platforms/android** o arquivo **gradle.properties**, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
cdvMinSdkVersion=20
```

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

cordova build android --release
```

Logo após importei o projeto no Android Studio 3.0.1:

<kbd>File</kbd> `>` <kbd>New</kbd> `>` <kbd>Import Project</kbd>

Naveguei para o diretorio da **myApp/platform** e selecionei a pasta **Android** e pressionei Ok.

Comment: Quem me dera fosse fácil assim kkkk não funfou não... Cara esse erro me assombra à anos e ninguém de nenhum lugar sabe como resolver.

Comment: Quais as versões dos itens do seu ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Comment: Até então está tudo atualizado...